# Making complex array initializations more readable

Tags: c++, array

I have a function in the C++ program, which does simple computations and writes result to two arrays - `result[53]` and `var1_new[53]`. It contains two code blocks:

The first one -

```
double result[53];

result[0] = ((var1[13] * 1) + (var2[7] * 2)) / var3[0];
result[1] = ((var1[21] * 1) + (var2[7] * 2)) / var3[1];
result[2] = ((var1[12] * 2) + (var2[7] * 3)) / var3[2];
result[3] = ((var1[25] * 2) + (var2[7] * 3)) / var3[3];
//And so on, up to result[52]
```

And the second one -

```
double var1_new[53];

for (int x = 0; x < 53; ++x)
{
    var1_new[x] = var1[x];
}

var1_new[13] += result[0];
var1_new[21] += result[1];
var1_new[12] += result[2];
var1_new[25] += result[3];
//And so on, up to var1_new[52]
```

The blocks above use *equal* array indexes *pattern* - `13, 21, 12, 15, etc`. The pattern is hardcoded.

This code runs pretty fast, thus I don't want to increase performance, but I'm thinking about readability - the function that contain code blocks is very complex. How can I make it more readable? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, **magic constants are bad**, you should name them

```
int const N = 53;
double result[N];
```

Second, **magic patterns are even worse**, you should also name them along with **documentation comments**

```
// explain where the pattern comes from
int const pattern[] = { 13, 21, 12, 25, /* 49 more constants */ };
```

Third, manually loop unrolling can sometimes help, but **only after you benchmarked**

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    result[i] = ((var1[pattern[i]] * (i+1)) + (var2[7] * (i+2))) / var3[i];
}
```

For your second part, rinse and repeat:

```
double var1_new[N];
```

Fourth, **use the Standard Library for standardized algorithms**

```
#include <algorithm>
std::copy_n(var1, N, var1_new);
```

Again, rinse and repeat the loop unrolling

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    var1_new[pattern[i]] += result[i];
}
```

Finally, you might want to give your variables **meaningful names**: `var1`, `var2`, `var3` do not explain **their intended use** very well. Think about what they mean in your application (it was unclear from the code fragment alone).